# share multiple DNS domain with multiple aws accounts by terraform in AWS Resource Access Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I'm forwarding DNS requests sent to a list of internal domains (on premise) by using AWS Route53 resolver. By terraform, I want to share the rules I created to other accounts of the company, so I have the following:

```
# I create as much share endpoint as domain I have, so If I have 30 domains, I'll make 30 endpoint RAM:
resource "aws_ram_resource_share" "endpoint_share" {
  count                     = length(var.forward_domain)
  name                      = "route53-${var.forward_domain[count.index]}-share"
  allow_external_principals = false
}
# Here I share every single endpoint with all the AWS ACcount we have 
resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "endpoint_ram_principal" {
  count              = length(var.resource_share_accounts)
  principal          = var.resource_share_accounts[count.index]

  resource_share_arn = {
    for item in aws_ram_resource_share.endpoint_share[*]:
        item.arn
  }
}
```

The last block, calls the arn output of the first one which is a list.
Now, this last block doesn't work, I don't know how to use multiple counts, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid 'for' expression

line 37: Key expression is required when building an object.
```

Any idea how to make this work?

```
Terraform version: 0.12.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets in resource_share_arn, like this:

```
resource_share_arn = [
  for item in aws_ram_resource_share.endpoint_share[*]:
    item.arn
]
```